# Develop SharePoint 2007 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2007

I’m new to SharePoint development. We are currently running SharePoint 2007, but we have Visual Studio 2010 installed on the development server. I’ve been successful developing web parts using class libraries in 2010, but I’m wondering if there are any templates for vs2010 that will still work on SharePoint 2007. Looks like all the templates built into VS2010 are for SharePoint 2010.

I've done some searches on SO and Google, I can't seem to find a good solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) works on VS2010 and has templates that you may use for SP 2007.